# Vue js 3 application not working in Mozilla Firefox apfter upgrading from Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, es6-promise, upgrade

[Error comings in console while raising axios requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCf0w.png)
[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj5UK.png)

Vue instance is getting created but whenever an axios requests is made to fetch data promise error is returned

```
fetchReports(body) {
    
    const inst = axios.create();
    store.state.currentListing = 'RecentReportListing';
    this.interceptRequest(inst, "setMyReportsInProgressStatus");
    this.interceptResponse(inst, "setMyReportsCompleteStatus");
    return inst
      .post(this.baseUrl() + "getReports", body, {
        headers: getAppConfig().headers
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.logHttpException(this.url, "getReports", error);
      });
  },
```

1. Tried removing babel/polyfill deprecated libraries and using core-js and runtime but still did not solve the issue .
2. Same code is running in chrome and Edge

Comment: Please post the code inside of `this.interceptResponse`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . These are two different errors, it's unknown how they are relatedm, the question lacks clear problem statement. The question cannot be answered in its current form. You need https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Currently it needs to be solved on your side. You can start with disabling the minifier and putting breakpoints in relevant lines that are shown in the error callstack